# How to get PathVariable (String) in a Controller method

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, path-variables

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/search/{email}")
    public String auditUseremail(@PathVariable("email") String email,Map<String, Object> map) {

        System.out.println(email);
}
```

this is my conroller class function, which is called when the action is `http://localhost:8080/LACASServer/secure/user/search/user@cohaesus.co.uk`

as u can look, email is in URL, but when i print it in the above method, i get it  `user@cohaesus.co`, can anybody tell me, what can be the issue and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use URL Encoding for this path and then decode it inside of controller

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode(email, "ISO-8859-1");
```

You can read more about it [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)